# Vuejs: invalid expression: Unexpected token ':' in http://example.com

Tags: laravel, vue.js

In my project using laravel 7. I'm using vue as frontend framework.

First in my controller I send only one attribute from my query into my template:

```php
        $sites = Site::with('users')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
        // This is the part
        $website_name = '';
        if (sizeof($sites) == 0) {
            // I fetch website attribute
            $website_name = Auth::user()->website;
        }
        return view('axcess.sites.edit', [
            'sites' => $sites,
            'website_name' => $website_name  // Send it into blade template
        ]);
```

In my blade template I send `$website_name` into component

```
<div class="row">
    <axcess-sites-edit
        :websiteName="{{ $website_name }}"
        :isNewUser="{{ sizeof($sites) == 0 }}"
    ></axcess-sites-edit>
</div>
```

The full vue component is this:

```js
<template>
<div class="col-md-8">
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" :disabled="isNewUser" v-model="website" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            websiteName: String,
            isNewUser: Boolean
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                website: this.websiteName
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Finally display the page as empty, in my console only display this error:

[image: Ouput result]

The problem comes from (`:`) symbol from `http://example.com`. There exists a solution for this to display into the input value.

Comment: There is a little possibility that there is an extra space/linebreak that messes up your html before or after :websiteName="{{ $website_name }}" and :isNewUser="{{ sizeof($sites) == 0 }}" ? Try to test it by putting them on one line just to make sure.

Comment: You also use all lower caps for `websitename` in the error screenshot, but your prop is `websiteName` which is probably the correct camel case spelling. This is probably the error, not the thing I mention above.

Comment: I have talked with my project manager.

The solution was add single quotation after the double quotation :
`<axcess-sites-edit :url="'{{ $website_name }}'" :is-new-user="{{ sizeof($sites) == 0 ? 'true' : 'false' }}" ></axcess-sites-edit>`

Also I have to update isNewUser prop.